# Identification of camera component including probable metal composition

Tags: identification, camera

I realize this is probably off topic but am curious as to what electronic component might be shown in the following picture, and what metal it likely is made off. It is presumably part of the triggering mechanism atop a digital camera (Canon Powershot A1100 IS):

[image]

Note this is a [follow up question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/121484/strange-sticky-substance-on-digital-camera) from another SE site.

It would additionally be useful to know what conditions would most probably have led to formation of the salt that accumulated on the device. It is unclear what humidity it was stored under, or whether a battery was in the device, but obviously it was not properly stored. Could leaving an undischarged battery in the device lead to this type of salt formation?

---

Update: According to the original OP, the image shows part of the battery door. It is used to complete the circuit between the two AA batteries that the camera takes. Scraping away the blue crystal only results in more of what you can already see in the picture. Metal that looks grey in some places and brown/red in others

Comment: Plated copper of some sort? If you scrape away the blue crystals, what's underneath?

Comment: @winny I'm inquiring (it's not my camera) but that makes sense. The blue salt could be oxidized nickel from nickel plating atop copper.

Comment: Check [here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/photo/canon/canon.a1100.battery.jpg) for a (bit unclear) picture of the battery compartment.

Comment: It is most likely badly corroded copper. Common salts of nickel are green and yellow, but blue forms are known. IMHO it is probably beyond repair, but see what you find when you gently scrape off the blue stuff. Don't let the scrapings drop into the camera! If you can get down to clean, bright metal it may be salvageable.

Comment: Thanks @PeterJennings and Huisman for the info. I leave the question open but don't know if this is regarded as useful by the site.

Comment: copper sulfate is blue

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Yes, thanks! I think it might be copper hydroxide from reaction of battery electrolyte with the conductor copper plating.